# Windows Forms - ErrorProvider + DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, errorprovider

How can I hook in the ErrorProvider with individual cells on the DataGridView control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can use the ErrorProvider in this manner, however the DataGridView has functionality built into it that's basically the same idea.

The idea is simple. A DataGridViewCell has an ErrorText property. What you do is, you handle the OnCellValidating event and if fails validation, you set the error text property, and you get that red error icon to show up in the cell. Here's some pseudo code:

```
public Form1()
{
    this.dataGridView1.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValidating);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.Validates(e.FormattedValue)) //run some custom validation on the value in that cell
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "Error";
                e.Cancel = true; //will prevent user from leaving cell, may not be the greatest idea, you can decide that yourself.
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried setting the ErrorText property. Nothing happens during runtime!

Comment: That's strange, it should work... Just make sure your ErrorText is not an empty string, because that removes the error.

Comment: It should work, I just tested it. The only thing I can think of, is that the DataGridView itself has a ShowCellErrors property. Make sure it's not set to false.

Comment: Just noticed there's a ShowCellErrors property on the DataGridView, maybe it's set to false?

Comment: Ok I have it showing the error. But I want them to be able to leave the cell. So I don't cancel the event. But that just throws up an ugly message box with a huge exception string and no error icon on the cell.

Comment: @RonnieOverby Instead of not setting `Cancel` you should set the property `AutoValidate` of the containing `Form`/`UserControl` to `EnableAllowFocusChange`. This will allow you to change focus even if you cancel validation.

Comment: This other post(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713988/winforms-problems-validating-a-cell-in-a-datagridview) was helpful to me when cell validation, and ErrorText didn't work as easily as they should.

Answer (score 10):

The problem I have with BFree's solution is that nothing shows up while the cell is in edit mode, but if I end edit, I get a data format error (because my value is a double).  I solved this by attaching the ErrorProvider directly to the cell edit control like this:

```
private ErrorProvider ep = new ErrorProvider();
private void DGV_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;
    double val;
    Control edit = DGV.EditingControl;
    if (edit != null && ! Double.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out val))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        ep.SetError(edit, "Numeric value required");
        ep.SetIconAlignment(edit, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleLeft);
        ep.SetIconPadding(edit, -20); // icon displays on left side of cell
    }
}

private void DGV_CellEndEdt(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    ep.Clear();
}
```

Comment: The solution, @Dada-Nada suggests is the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

You can just implement `IDataErrorInfo` into your BusinessObjects, and set the BindingSource as DataSource for the ErrorProvider too. That way your BusinessObject intern validation shows up in the DataGrid and on all fields the objects are bound to automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void myGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
    var cell = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if ( ... ) // Validation success
    {
        cell.ErrorText = string.Empty;
        return;
    }

    dataGridView.EndEdit();
    cell.ErrorText = error;
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column (like DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) to dataGridView.Columns that has the CellTemplate set to your own implementation (say, inherited from DataGridViewTextBoxCell). Then in your implementation - handle validation as you like - rendering and positioning of the editing panel to fit your needs.

You can check a sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(VS.80).aspx.

But then again - there might be a simpler solution.