# Winforms: Problems validating a cell in a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to validate a Winforms **datagridview** cell with **CellValidating**. If a value was not set correctly by the user I set **ErrorText** and use `e.Cancel`, so that the cursor remains in the cell.
The problem is now, that the **error-symbol** (and the **error text**) is not displayed (in the cell). When I delete e.Cancel the cell looses the focus and error-symbol is displayed. How can I achieve that the cell remains in edit mode and the error-symbol is displayed too?

```
if (...)
{
   this.datagridviewX.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "Errortext";
   e.Cancel = true;
}
else
{
   this.datagridviewX.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "";
}
```

Comment: As I say in my answer - what you are describing isn't the out of the box behaviour so you must be doing something unusual. Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 12):

The behaviour you are seeing is actually due to a painting issue and not due to the error icon not being shown. What is happening is that when you set the cell's error text the icon is displayed but the text box of the cell in edit mode is painted over the icon, hence no icon shown to the user!

You have two options for fixing this - one is to simply use the row's error text so instead of:

```
this.datagridviewX.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "Errortext";  
e.Cancel = true;
```

You have:

```
this.datagridviewX.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Errortext";
e.Cancel = true;
```

The other option is to change the cell padding of the cell (moving the editing control) and painting the icon in.

I actually found this technique for solving the problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/28d812bb-5f33-46d6-94dd-6a2d1f442a29) and reproduced their code below (in C# and not VB.Net).

First you have your cell validating event where you add some code to change the cell padding:

```
void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        cell.ErrorText =
            "Company Name must not be empty";

        if (cell.Tag == null)
        {
            cell.Tag = cell.Style.Padding;
            cell.Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 18, 0);
        }
        e.Cancel = true;

    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

That allows the icon to be seen not the editing control has moved, except the icon has moved too! So we also need to paint a new icon.

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorText))
        {
            GraphicsContainer container = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(18,0);
            e.Paint(this.ClientRectangle, DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon);
            e.Graphics.EndContainer(container);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you end editing on the cell you need to reset the padding:

```
void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorText))
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        cell.ErrorText = string.Empty;
        cell.Style.Padding = (Padding)cell.Tag;
        cell.Tag = null;
    }
}
```

The post where I found this neglects to set the mouse over for the new painted icon - Here is some rough code that addresses that, I don't have time to get it really working so there are some slight fudges that thought would fix - I'll tidy that up if I get a minute later.

I set DataGridView.ShowCellToolTips = true and introduce a boolean inError to track if we currently have an editing error. I then handle the MouseHover event:

```
void dataGridView1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inError)
    {                
        Point pos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);               

        if (r.Contains(pos.X - 20, pos.Y - 5))
        {                   
            t.Show("There was an error", dataGridView1.EditingControl, 3000); 
        }
    }
}
```

The t in that code is a form level ToolTip control, and r is a rectangle.

I populate r as below in the cell painting handler:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorText))
        {            
            GraphicsContainer container = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();

            r = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(18, 0);
            e.Paint(this.ClientRectangle, DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon);
            e.Graphics.EndContainer(container);            

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not happy about the minus 20 and minus 5 on the position point - that is what I'd fix up if I had a bit more time.

Comment: I tried exactly this with dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = ...

Comment: @Kottan provide some code (probably best for the whole form if not too big) and we can have a look.

Comment: @Kottan - ok, got you now. Your question didn't make it clear at all that you were setting the error on the cell and not the row. Providing code is always a good thing to do.

Comment: It works if I only use dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText. The error icon is shown in the row header (not in the cell).

Comment: Hi, I have a custom editor hosted in the cell and the notify error icon is not shown in the cell, it is shown as a white area but when mouse is over this area, the tooltip is shown. However, with standard datagridviewcolumns, both notify error icon and tooltip is shown so what's wrong? I use ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl to apply cell style to the editor in order to apply the same padding.

Comment: David, your answer was very helpful along with the link to where you found the technique. Although I was able to get the error icon painted in and showing visibly, the form-level ToolTip has never worked when hovering over the cell....and debugging a mouse pointer location in an event-handler never seems to work right!