# Confusion regarding DataGridView CellValidation

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how cell validation works, but I'm not getting the intended effect with my code. The cell fails to validate if the input isn't a valid Double, but the error text doesn't come up unless I hit escape, which returns the cell to the previous value. I want the error text to show up when the invalid input is entered, otherwise it's confusing...

EDIT: I want the error text to show up while the cell is being edited, is that possible?

```
private void coordDGV_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            double result;
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= 3)
            {
                if (!Double.TryParse(coordDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out result))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    coordDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "Needs to be positive or negative decimal";
                }
                else
                {
                    coordDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "";
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you move the `e.Cancel = true` to after the `ErrorText` assignment, does anything happen?

Comment: @JDDavis No difference I can tell. Seems to act the same either way.

Answer (score 2):

[I found this post which basically covered my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713988/winforms-problems-validating-a-cell-in-a-datagridview)

I was wondering why

```
this.datagridviewX.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Errortext";
```

wasn't showing up, but I realized it was because the error icon shows in the row header and I had row headers turned off! Unfortunately error icons can't be in column headers, so I reluctantly turned the row header on and it solved everything nicely!

Comment: Also, there is a [DataGridViewCell.ErrorText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.errortext?view=netframework-4.8) that can be used.

Comment: @JQSOFT is that not what I'm doing in my original code?I rewrote my code to test this explicitly and it still only shows the errortext when I hit 'escape' on the invalid entry.

Comment: Right. My apologies.